# Using text as a background instead of image on html page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use text as a background image for a site - it's fine if the text reflows automatically, but I'm trying to not scroll the page - so on my body I have overflow:hidden, which works fine, unless my content div gets too long, at which point it is hidden too.

Is there a way to make the "background" layer overflow:hidden, while letting my content flow as necessary? (I've tried the obvious overflow:hidden on #background)

```
<body>
<div id="content">
  All my content
</div>
<div id="background">
<p>'I told some of yo... lots of text</p>
</div>
</body>
```

is the basic page format so far and the css is:

```
body {overflow:hidden;}

#background {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
    right:-20px;
    bottom:-20px;
    left:-20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:-1;}

#content {
    width:840px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:auto;
    overflow:visible;}
```

Comment: with an `overflow: auto` on the `body` it will scroll only with the content...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `#background` position fixed and set the overflow:hidden to it, not the body.

```
body {}

#background {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:95%; 
    height:95%;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/Av6YW/

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a way around using background:fixed, (but I couldn't get that working either.)