# Stop written text used as background from pushing content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to use text as the background for a page and would like the main content of the body to be shown over that text.  The method shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046193/using-text-as-a-background-instead-of-image-on-html-page) works for static text, but my text is printed dynamically using jquery.

Here's what I have so far:

html

```
<h1>body content </h1>
```

css

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster);

#msg{
    text-align:left;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family:lobster;
    color:#bb4e28;
    float:none;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

jquery

```
var showText = function (target, message, index, interval) {
    if (index < message.length) {
        $(target).append(message[index++]);
        setTimeout(function () {
            showText(target, message, index, interval);
        }, interval);
    }
};

$(function () {

    showText("#msg", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In viverra risus et nunc fermentum sed iaculis tortor rhoncus. Nulla facilisi. Nulla pharetra libero sed urna semper eu viverra orci volutpat. Mauris est dolor, porta ut sollicitudin sit amet, molestie vitae lectus. ", 0, 20);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J7JTB/

You can see right now the background text is pushing the rest of the content down.  What I would like is for it to print behind the content, and not cause the page to scroll if it reaches a certain length.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can simply put an absolute position to your #msg container, or to the body content, depending on how you want to lock things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#msg {
    position: fixed;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/J7JTB/3/

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `#msg` CSS:

```
position: absolute;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/J7JTB/1/

Comment: That stopped the content from being pushed, but the page still scrolls if the text exceeds the page area.  Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: I'm sure there is, most likely using the `.scrollTop()` method, however, I'm unsure how to use it.